# How do you modify your Mii?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

I'm playing MK8 on Switch and everybody seems to have custom Miis.

But for the life of me I can't seem to find where the option to customize my Mii is.

Pretty sure I'm missing the obvious, but where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Switch main menu:

- System Settings
- Scroll down to Mii menu
- Create/Edit a Mii
- Choose a Mii and press Edit

From Mario Kart 8 main menu:

- Play Stats (the bottom left icon)
- Press X to change your current Mii
- Choose the Mii you want to use